# How to display an ArrayList in a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I need to add an `Activity` where I can list the elements of an `ArrayList<CustomClass>` and I've seen there's a newer and better way to display lists - `RecyclerView`.

My question is how to implement this into my app.
I've found that I need to use an `Adapter`, but I don't quite understand how to implement the whole process correctly.

If you're wondering, I'm referring to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) examples of the docs, which I have been reading.

EDIT:

After having updated my code, it says it cannot resolve the symbol `setOnEntryClickListener`:

```
public class voting extends Activity {


RecyclerView myList;
private ArrayList<Player> players; // Players


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_voting);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    players = (ArrayList<Player>)bundle.getSerializable("PLAYERS");

    myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.charactersList);
    myList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    CoursesAdapter adapter = new CoursesAdapter(players);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

// OR RecyclerView with a click listener

CoursesAdapter clickAdapter = new CoursesAdapter(players);
clickAdapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new CoursesAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
        // stuff that will happen when a list item is clicked
    }
});
recyclerView.setAdapter(clickAdapter);
}
```

So I've thought I had put that `interface` in the wrong place (very probably), infact I've put it in the Adapter class, at the end of it, right after the `onAttachedToRecyclerView()` Method:

```
    @Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}


private OnEntryClickListener mOnEntryClickListener;

public interface OnEntryClickListener {
    void onEntryClick(View view, int position);
}

public void setOnEntryClickListener(OnEntryClickListener onEntryClickListener) {
    mOnEntryClickListener = onEntryClickListener;
}



}
```

Comment: There is a full sample here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I remember when I was first reading about `RecyclerView`s - I agree it can be a little confusing at first. Hopefully, this explanation will help you understand it better.

---

## RecyclerView basics

### 1. Adding the `RecyclerView`

First you need to add your `RecyclerView` to your XML layout. I'm assuming you know how to do this. You also declare it in your Java code:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.your_recycler_view);
```

### 2. Creating the `Adapter` and understanding `ViewHolder`

Next, you need to create an **`Adapter`** for it. This is a class that implements `RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.YourViewHolder>`. I will explain what this means in a minute.

I believe it helps to look at an example of an `Adapter` to understand how it works (e.g. [one I created](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/FlashcardsApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/satsumasoftware/flashcards/ui/adapter/CoursesAdapter.java) for an open-source app). I would also highly recommend looking through a set of Java files I have made as an example on Gist on GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/7646564f48ee708c1582c013e1de4f07

I will be referencing the example files from the link above in this explanation so you can follow along.

You can see that the `Adapter` class contains an inner class, which is your `ViewHolder`. Therefore, it needs to extend `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

Inside this `ViewHolder`, you declare the variables for the layouts that will be used for each list item in your `RecyclerView`. In the constructor for your `ViewHolder`, you assign these variables. I'm referring to this part of the code (I'm giving my example below):

```
ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    text1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
}
```

That's all you need for your `ViewHolder` (the inner class in your `Adapter`).

### 3. Understanding the `Adapter`

Like most Java objects, you will need to have a constructor some private variables in your `Adapter` class. Here are mine:

```
private ArrayList<CustomClass> mCustomObjects;

public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<CustomClass> arrayList) {
    mCustomObjects = arrayList;
}
```

You will need to have your `ArrayList<CustomClass>` as a constructor parameter so you can pass the list so your `Adapter` can use it.

If you look at the rest of the `Adapter` class, it contains some methods which it overrides from what it extends. Let's have a quick look at what these are:

- `getItemCount()` returns the size of your list.
- `onCreateViewHolder(...)` is used to inflate the layout for your list item.
- `onBindViewHolder(...)` configures your layouts for the list item (e.g. setting text to a `TextView`)

For most cases, `getItemCount()` will just return the `size()` of your `ArrayList<CustomClass>`.

The `onCreateViewHolder(...)` method generally stays the same too:

```
@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);
    return new ExampleViewHolder(view);
}
```

You can see that I am inflating the layout that I will use as my list item (`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`). This layout is built in to Android so I don't need to create it - of course, your can use whatever layout you wish and then modify your `Adapter` for widgets that you may be using. The return type of this method will match whatever you named your `ViewHolder` inner class.

Now, the interesting bit is in `onBindViewHolder(...)`. You configure your layouts here, so it is completely up to you what you want to do. Here's a template you could use:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CustomClass object = mCustomObjects.get(position);

    String firstText = object.getFirstText()
    String secondText = object.getSecondText()

    holder.text1.setText(firstText);
    holder.text2.setText(secondText);
}
```

Basically, you access your `ViewHolder` variables (for the widgets in your list item layout) by doing `holder.myWidget`. The `holder` part is coming from the parameter, which is your `ViewHolder` we talked about earlier, and `myWidget` would be the name of the `View` variable from that.

In the example above, the `object` has a `getFirstText()` method, and the `ViewHolder` contains a `TextView` (`text1`), so I am setting the text.

There is also one more method - `onAttachedToRecyclerView(...)`. You can use this for more complex things, but at a basic level, it is usually this:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

### 4. Configuring `RecyclerView`

Remember at the beginning, when we declared and assigned our `RecyclerView`?:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.your_recycler_view);
```

Now we are going to configure it.

You start by setting a "layout manager". This determines how each list item will be displayed on screen. The common ones are `LinearLayoutManager` and `GridLayoutManager`. The former puts your list items into a standard list (nothing special really, but it is very useful), and the latter organises your list items into a grid type of layout.

In our example, we're going to use a `LinearLayoutManager`. To set this on the `RecyclerView`, we do this:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

That's all.

And all we have to do next is to set the `Adapter` class we created and customised earlier to your `RecyclerView`:

```
ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter(yourCustomArrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In the above, I'm assuming your `adapter` only has one parameter, but this will depend on how you configured it earlier.

### 5. Using your `RecyclerView`

The steps above should give you a working `RecyclerView`. If you get stuck, you can look at how I added one into my app [here](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/FlashcardsApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/satsumasoftware/flashcards/ui/adapter/CoursesAdapter.java).

You can also look through the [Google samples for the `RecyclerView` implementation](https://www.github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView).

I hope all of this gave you a clear idea about how `RecyclerView` works.

---

## Adding a click listener

You may want to add a click listener so that you are not using the `RecyclerView` just for displaying items.

To do this, your inner `ViewHolder` class needs to implement `View.OnClickListener`. This is because you will set an `OnClickListener` to the `itemView` parameter of the `ViewHolder`'s constructor. Let me show you what I mean:

```
public class ExampleClickViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView text1, text2;

    ExampleClickViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        // we do this because we want to check when an item has been clicked:
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        // now, like before, we assign our View variables
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        subtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // The user may not set a click listener for list items, in which case our listener
        // will be null, so we need to check for this
        if (mOnEntryClickListener != null) {
            mOnEntryClickListener.onEntryClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

The only other things you need to add are a custom interface for your `Adapter` and a setter method:

```
private OnEntryClickListener mOnEntryClickListener;

public interface OnEntryClickListener {
    void onEntryClick(View view, int position);
}

public void setOnEntryClickListener(OnEntryClickListener onEntryClickListener) {
    mOnEntryClickListener = onEntryClickListener;
}
```

So your new, click-supporting `Adapter` is complete.

Now, let's use it...

```
ExampleClickAdapter clickAdapter = new ExampleClickAdapter(yourObjects);
clickAdapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new ExampleClickAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
        // stuff that will happen when a list item is clicked
    }
});
recyclerView.setAdapter(clickAdapter);
```

It's basically how you would set up a normal `Adapter`, except that you use your setter method that you created to control what you will do when your user clicks a particular list item.

---

To reiterate, you can look through a set of examples I made on this Gist on GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/7646564f48ee708c1582c013e1de4f07

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114890/discussion-on-answer-by-farbod-salamat-zadeh-how-to-display-an-arraylist-in-a-re).

Comment: How can we use data binding to repeat an EditText in the xml file for any object in an arraylist and assign specific data field to be shown there?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example, hope it will help you :

```
public class BankListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BankListAdapter.BankListViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<BankListModel> bankListModels;
    FragmentActivity activity;
    View selectBank;

    public BankListAdapter(ArrayList<BankListModel> bankListModels, FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.bankListModels=bankListModels;
        this.activity=activity;
    }


    @Override
    public BankListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View bankListLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_bank_list, null);
        BankListViewHolder bankListViewHolder = new BankListViewHolder(bankListLayout);
        return bankListViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BankListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bankName.setText(bankListModels.get(position).getBankName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bankListModels.size();
    }

    public class BankListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView bankName;

        public BankListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            bankName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_bankName);
            selectBank = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_selectBank);

        }
    }
}
```