# Recycle view showing single item from firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My JSON is:

```
{
  "Ingredient": {
    "hgO9joLhmfh4Wjn7xYpyqcYmNOB3": {
      "Garlic": {
        "Expiry": "2022-11-12",
        "Ingredient": 1
      },
      "Onion": {
        "Expiry": "2022-11-12",
        "Ingredient": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where `hgO9joLhmfh4Wjn7xYpyqcYmNOB3` is the current user UID. The problem here is RecycleView shows only a single item from the database which in my case is `Onion` node. Why didn't it loop for each children under the `fridgeRef.child(currentUserID)` node?

**java code**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ingredientView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fridge, container, false);
    
    myIngredientList = (RecyclerView) ingredientView.findViewById(R.id.ingredientList);
    myIngredientList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    fridgeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ingredient");
    return ingredientView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<fridgeItem> options
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<fridgeItem>()
                    .setQuery(fridgeRef , fridgeItem.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<fridgeItem, fridgeViewHolder> adapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<fridgeItem, fridgeViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull fridgeViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull fridgeItem model) {

            fridgeRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                        if(snapshot.child("Garlic").hasChild("Ingredient")){
                            String itemName = "Garlic";
                            String itemExpiry = snapshot.child("Garlic").child("Expiry").getValue().toString();

                            holder.ingredName.setText(itemName);
                            holder.ingredExpiry.setText(itemExpiry);
                        }

                        if(snapshot.child("Onion").hasChild("Ingredient")){
                            String itemName = "Onion";
                            String itemExpiry = snapshot.child("Onion").child("Expiry").getValue().toString();

                            holder.ingredName.setText(itemName);
                            holder.ingredExpiry.setText(itemExpiry);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public fridgeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ingredientrecycle, parent, false);
            fridgeViewHolder viewHolder = new fridgeViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };

    myIngredientList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}

public static class fridgeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView ingredName, ingredExpiry;

    public fridgeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ingredName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        ingredExpiry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemExpiry);
    }
}
```

**ingredientrecycle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ingred"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemExpiry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/expiry"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/delete_icon"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**fragment_fridge.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fridge">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fridge"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FF5D36"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fridgetext"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="32dp"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                android:paddingTop="32dp">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/ingredientList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="615dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: How `fridgeRef ` defined?

Comment: fridgeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ingredient"); @AlexMamo

Comment: Please also show us the layout file used in the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapters from FirebaseUI are designed to show a single child view for each direct child node at the path where you attach the adapter in the database.

In your case, you attach the adapter to `/Ingredient`, so it creates a single view for each child node of `/Ingredient`, which is just one child node for `hgO9joLhmfh4Wjn7xYpyqcYmNOB3`. In that child node you then read handle both its `Garlic` and `Onion` properties, but you're setting their values on the same view holder - so you end up only seeing the values from `Onion`.

---

If you want to show all ingredients for `/Ingredient/hgO9joLhmfh4Wjn7xYpyqcYmNOB3`, you should attach the adapter to *that* path and simplify its handling to:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<fridgeItem> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<fridgeItem>()
                .setQuery(fridgeRef.child("hgO9joLhmfh4Wjn7xYpyqcYmNOB3") , fridgeItem.class)
                .build();

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<fridgeItem, fridgeViewHolder> adapter
        = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<fridgeItem, fridgeViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull fridgeViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull fridgeItem model) {

        // String itemName = "Garlic"; TODO: 
        String itemExpiry = model.getExpiry();

        holder.ingredName.setText(itemName);
        holder.ingredExpiry.setText(itemExpiry);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public fridgeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ingredientrecycle, parent, false);
        fridgeViewHolder viewHolder = new fridgeViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }
};

myIngredientList.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.startListening();
```

You'll still need to get the `itemName` from the database here. If that's not in your `fridgeItem` class yet, you can get it with something like `getRef(position).getKey()` iirc.

---

If you want to show all ingredients for all users, that doesn't fit with the logic of the adapters in FirebaseUI, and you're probably better off creating your own adapter.

1. Attach a listener to `/Ingredients` as you already do.
2. Loop over the `getChildren()` of the data snapshot to get the snapshot for each user.
3. Loop over the children of each user snapshot to get to the individual ingredients.
4. Add the data for each ingredient to an array list.
5. Create an [adapter on that array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786796/how-to-display-an-arraylist-in-a-recyclerview)

Comment: i only want to show for the current user whos currently logged in to the app. where `currentUserID` defined to get the current user

Comment: Are you asking [how to get the current user ID from Firebase Authentication in Android?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+the+current+user+ID+from+Firebase+Authentication+in+Android)

Comment: I'm sorry if my question isn't clear. What I'm trying todo here is to get all the item that current user has with my JSON structure to RecyclerView. Im stucked as the RecycleView only showing 1 item to the RecycleView.

Comment: I understood that part, and explained in my answer both why that is - and how to address that. Did the explanation in the first section of my answer make sense? If so, and you want to show the ingredients for a single user, did you try to apply the changes I gave in the second part?

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution to my code. The snapshot.child() showing error and I  added ValueEventListener() to use the snapshot reference. The recyclerview didnt return any value

Comment: In the code in the second section of my answer you don't need a `ValueEventListener`. What's the error you got?

Comment: If i copy ur code and add it into mine, the snapshot keyword will become error showing cannot resolve symbol 'snapshot'. The recycle option also which `FirebaseRecyclerOptions<fridgeItem> options` also showing ";"  expected

Comment: im still try to repair my code but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Aha. Yeah, you can probably get the expiry from the `model` object - so I updated my answer for that.

Comment: Thank you so much, i've got exactly want i tried to do. Just at `FirebaseRecyclerOptions<fridgeItem> options` , i need to add equal sign else it'll shows error.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put the conditions inside  the foreach loop

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<fridgeItem> option
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){

                    
                    if(snapshot.child("Garlic").hasChild("Ingredient")){
                        String itemName = "Garlic";
                        String itemExpiry = snapshot.child("Garlic").child("Expiry").getValue().toString();

                        holder.ingredName.setText(itemName);
                        holder.ingredExpiry.setText(itemExpiry);
                    }

                    if(snapshot.child("Onion").hasChild("Ingredient")){
                        String itemName = "Onion";
                        String itemExpiry = snapshot.child("Onion").child("Expiry").getValue().toString();

                        holder.ingredName.setText(itemName);
                        holder.ingredExpiry.setText(itemExpiry);
                    }
}
}
```

Comment: my bad, i forgot to edit the code when i put code inside the loop. I've repaired in the question. Still its showing single container

Comment: Ok, I'll check your code later if I'll see something odd I'll let you know :)