# Android: Onclick not working in VerticalGridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have an activity which creates a fragment with VerticalGridView.
In activity I have this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        if (fragment.handleKeyDown(keyCode)) {
            return true;
        }

        // todo swallow some events
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Since I need to do some special treatment for UP, DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT so I override this `onKeyDown`.

Then I have a custom viewHolder `GridItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, in this viewHolder I have:

```
    gridItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LOG.d("onclick!!");
            }
        });
```

But this onclick method is never called when I press "Enter". Am I missing something here? Is `onKeyDown` override the `onClick`?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use OnItemClickListener for GridView

gridItemView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int i, long id) {
        LOG.d("onclick!!"+i);
```

}
        });

Comment: I tried this too, still not working. So I put logs in onKeyDown and it showed up for enter key which I think this method might override the onclick.

Comment: Can you post your coding? is there any error shown in log cat did you check it with Toast.

Comment: My viewholder looks exactly like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32780492 . And I figured that `onKeyDown` is not overriding the `onClick`, I removed `onKeyDown`, still not working.

Comment: where did you use OnItemClickListener? are you using in Activity?

Comment: use the above answer in your activity