# Recycle View holder on click listener not triggered

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listener

I have recyclerview with a listener. I use this code :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


   //just setting the textview etc



    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Model_NewProg model_newProg = ListOfExo.get(position);
            openDialog(model_newProg, position);
        }
    });
}
```

and my xml for the adapter is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_space"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
            android:layout_height="5dp">


        </View>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_space"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_exo_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColorHint="#aeafaf"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_temps_pause"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColorHint="#aeafaf"
            android:textSize="15dp" />


    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/lay1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_nbr_séries"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColorHint="#aeafaf"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_nbr_rep"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColorHint="#aeafaf"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

for some reason, if I click on the cell the listener on the holder doesn't trigger. Well sometimes it triggers if I aim the corner of the textview. But it seems that the text view is "blocking" the listener... I have to try to add android:clickable=false; android:clickable=true; ,... not working

Does anyone has an idea? I use this code everytime and it always work

Comment: Use onclick listener inside ViewHolder class,

Answer (score 0):

The `holder.itemView` must be changed to : `holder.theIdOfTheElementYouWantToClick`

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement `View.onClickListener` in `ViewHolder` class then register it in the `constructure`  see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780492/8660721) answer for more details

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//do what you want
}

    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. if I put listener to all the text view, it works but that's not what I'am looking for. I want that when I click anywhere on the cell it triggers the listener. Normally the holder.ItemView.setOnClickListener should work but I don't understand what is the problem here

Comment: so you have to register the itemview it self to do what you want and this is the correct way  because putting a lisener in onBindViewHolder it is bad idea

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845846/why-is-adding-an-onclicklistener-inside-onbindviewholder-of-a-recyclerview-adapt

Comment: yes I understand, i'm trying to do your way but in the onCreateViewHolder the line  ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v); isn't working. It forces me to write : "        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v);
" and it says that ViewHolder is abstract it can't be instantiated
Maybe I miss a library ?

Comment: @MohammadSommakia you coppied my answer..its not ImageView its CardView.. ;)

Comment: @MohammadSommakia how it is different from my code for compiler

Comment: because you are setting the listener in the constructure but i override it from the interface

Answer (score 0):

Assign `id` to your **cardView** and fetch it in `ViewHolder` class and perform onClick on this id within ViewHolder class. For example.. if your cardView `id` is **cardView**

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public CardView rowCardView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        rowCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        rowCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //add your code..
            }
        });

    }}
```

Comment: It is not working 
It's weird, only works if I hit the left corner of the cell

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is a problem of parent or something like this
I even tried to put on the onBindViewHolder method a listener to the CardView and still it doesn't trigger, just like the textview took the click instead of the CardView

Comment: well it is happening

Comment: @ImNeos try by giving RelativeLayout width = match_parent