# Adapter Android Studio Button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have an adapter with a button inside and I don't really know ho to do something when I presse the button.
It's an order app and in the the basket I have a delete button to delete a dish.
Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can find the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37846430/

Instead of implementing the `View.OnClickListener` in the `ExampleClickViewHolder`, you should be fine with simply setting an `onClickListener` to your button and call the `mOnEntryClickListener.onEntryClick` in it.

For a more reliable answer, please add some details on your current code.

Comment: j'avais déjà regardé et j'utilise binding car notre prof le veut mais c'est bon j'ai mis le clic dans l'adapter le soucis que j'ai c'est actualiser l'adapter

Answer (score 0):

So I put the code of the button in the adapter and I put in it
""list.removeAt(position)
notifyDataSetChanged()""